# Not able to set password in PAM module using pam_set_item()

Tags: c, linux, pam

I have created a custom PAM module to login to Linux using my custom authentication method.
After my module is done authenticating it receives the actual username and password (plaintext) of the Linux user account from a db.

Now I am trying to set the username and password using:

`pam_set_item(pamh, PAM_USER, user)` and `pam_set_item(pamh, PAM_AUTHTOK, passwd)`, after doing `pam_start("m_pamconf", user, &conv, &pamh)`.

The "m_pamconf" is my pam configuration file which contains:

```
auth    pam_unix.so nullok_secure  use_first_pass
```

The username is set successfully using this but the password doesn't seem to work, as I am getting a password prompt (which of course should not happen if it takes the password that i have supplied).

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

I'm getting the password prompt when I use the `try_first_pass` flag,
if I instead use `use_first_pass`, the module simply fails and gives the following error in debug logs:

`auth could not identify password for [username]`

This is my /etc/pam.d/sudo :

```
#%PAM-1.0

# my pam test
auth    requisite       pam_test.so

session    required   pam_env.so readenv=1 user_readenv=0
session    required   pam_env.so readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale user_readenv=0
@include common-auth
@include common-account
@include common-session-noninteractive
```

The first line uses the module that I have created and from which I am trying to authenticate the user by doing `pam_start("mypamd", user, &conv, &pamh)` and then `pam_authenticate(pamh, 0)` using the auth method of pam_unix.so as specified above in "m_pamconf".

Comment: A password should _never_ be saved in plain text anywhere.

Comment: If you get a password prompt, then I would suspect that your custom PAM module is either ignored completely (wrong setup?) or fails and is followed by another authentication strategy.

Comment: @arkascha The password is not stored in plaintext. What I mean is that I'm setting the password in plaintext. 

and I have set my pam's config as "requisite", so, I'm quite sure it's not using another module for auth.

Comment: Also, the module is not ignored as I'm getting debug consoles from it.

Comment: Well, in your question you wrote: "it receives the actual username and password (plaintext) of the Linux user account from a db". How that if it is not stored as such?

Comment: We cannot tell you if other modules are tried too, but it looks like. This obviously is up to your own setup of the PAM strategy which you did not post. Keep in mind that modules may include others, so you might need to follow a few configuration paths...

Comment: @arkascha .. password is stored AES encrypted and decrypted by the module itself before setting using pam_set_item().
I have edited my question to clarify a bit. Do you think it can still use other modules considering the responses I'm getting ?

Comment: I already answered to the question you ask. We have no access to your system, so we do not know your PAM setup since you did not post any details about that. How to you expect us to say anything helpful to that?

Comment: About the password being stored in a DB: ok, I will rephrase my initial comment: A password should _never_ be saved in a decryptable form anywhere. What you store instead is a _hash_, a good _hash_ of a password. Then, at authentication time you again hash the provided password using the same hashing salt as for the original password and then compare the two hashes. That protects your users accounts, since breaking stolen passwords get's much more complex that way.

Comment: @arkascha.. Ok, I get it about the password encryption. I have posted the conf file too now.

Comment: @CodeShow what's the return value of `pam_set_item(pamh, PAM_AUTHTOK, passwd)`?

Comment: So what authentication strategies do those included modules (configurations) inject? That is what I referred to above when mentioning the configurations paths you will have to follow...

Comment: @arkascha do you even know the answer to how to call a function which verifies the password of the user like pam_authtoken, by passing the password to it as a argument.
This whole convo seems to be useless.OP is trying to create a custom module which return the password of the user, and now he is trying to verify the local user with the password which his custom PAM module has returned.

Comment: @user5821368 I implemented a number of PAM modules myself... But ok, maybe I completely miss something here. Have fun, all!

Answer (score 1):

You may need to set the module to sufficient. Having it set to requisite means that it is required to execute, and will fail the stack immediately if it returns false. It does not mean that it will make the stack succeed. According to the docks (http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/sag-configuration-file.html)

> For the simple (historical) syntax valid control values are:
>
> required
>
> ```
> failure of such a PAM will ultimately lead to the PAM-API returning failure but only after the remaining stacked modules (for
> ```
>
> this service and type) have been invoked.
>
> requisite
>
> ```
> like required, however, in the case that such a module returns a failure, control is directly returned to the application or to the
> ```
>
> superior PAM stack. The return value is that associated with the first
> required or requisite module to fail. Note, this flag can be used to
> protect against the possibility of a user getting the opportunity to
> enter a password over an unsafe medium. It is conceivable that such
> behavior might inform an attacker of valid accounts on a system. This
> possibility should be weighed against the not insignificant concerns
> of exposing a sensitive password in a hostile environment.
>
> sufficient
>
> ```
> if such a module succeeds and no prior required module has failed the PAM framework returns success to the application or to the
> ```
>
> superior PAM stack immediately without calling any further modules in
> the stack. A failure of a sufficient module is ignored and processing
> of the PAM module stack continues unaffected.
>
> optional
>
> ```
> the success or failure of this module is only important if it is the only module in the stack associated with this service+type.
> ```
>
> include
>
> ```
> include all lines of given type from the configuration file specified as an argument to this control.  substack
>
> include all lines of given type from the configuration file specified as an argument to this control. This differs from include in
> ```
>
> that evaluation of the done and die actions in a substack does not
> cause skipping the rest of the complete module stack, but only of the
> substack. Jumps in a substack also can not make evaluation jump out of
> it, and the whole substack is counted as one module when the jump is
> done in a parent stack. The reset action will reset the state of a
> module stack to the state it was in as of beginning of the substack
> evaluation.